# Determinate loop and Indeterminate Loops in Python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, nested-loops

I need to show "Determinate loop" and "Indeterminate Loops" on this code. (nested)

This is a simple code, pick a random number, and gives you 2 opportunities to guess the number, if you can't, it will let you know what the magic number was and start the game again.

questions:
is there any other way to make the game start over? like a while or nested loop.
can I get an opinion if it is enough?

the problem with the code is, every time you make a guess, it prints

```
 "Can you guess the magic number?"
```

how can it print that only at the beginning of the code and then only prints:

```
"try a lower number"
"try a higher number"
```

I feel like the code is not nested enough, anyway I can make it more professional?

```py
repeat_the_game = True
def start():
    import random
    magic_number = random.randint(1, 10)
    trying = 0
    limit = 2
    while trying < limit:
        guess = int(input("can you guess the magic number?"))
        trying += 1
        if guess > magic_number:
            print("try a lower number")
        elif guess < magic_number:
            print("try a higher number")
        elif guess == magic_number:
            print("wow, you are right")
            break
    else:
        print("sorry, the magic number was", magic_number)

while repeat_the_game:
    start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the text out of the loop to a print statement. Then you can still keep fetching the input inside the loop:

```
repeat_the_game = True
def start():
    import random
    magic_number = random.randint(1, 10)
    trying = 0
    limit = 2
    print("can you guess the magic number?")
    while trying < limit:
        trying += 1
        guess = int(input())
        if guess > magic_number:
            print("try a lower number")
        elif guess < magic_number:
            print("try a higher number")
        elif guess == magic_number:
            print("wow, you are right")
            break
    else:
        print("sorry, the magic number was", magic_number)

while repeat_the_game:
    start()
```

However, if the second guess is still wrong you probably don't want to print "try a lower/higher number". If you guess it right the second time you do want to print "wow, you're right". I'd put the "try a lower/higher number" after an additional check of whether all tries have been used up already. You can move the "wow, you're right" part before that check:

```
while trying < limit:
    guess = int(input())
    trying += 1
    if guess == magic_number:
        print("wow, you are right")
        break
    if trying == limit:
        continue
    if guess > magic_number:
        print("try a lower number")
    elif guess < magic_number:
        print("try a higher number")
else:
    print("sorry, the magic number was", magic_number)
```

Comment: It seems to be more complicated than that;
when I take the input out of the loop, it will print it once but as soon as you enter a number it will end the game and start over the game.

about the second suggestion part, 
it would just continue the game without letting you make any progress so every time you enter something it starts the game over again, it also prints the first statement again